# Passing QApplication object from main exe to DLL

Tags: qt

I have a QT GUI application loading a non GUI QT dll. I need to be able to access the QApplication object inside the DLL. How can i do this? I tried QCoreApplication::instance(), but this returns null. Without having the object from the main GUI, i am not able to process events in the DLL. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Ok. After some reading, i got it figured out. In the DLL that is getting loaded, if i do QCoreApplication::instance(), i am able to get the instance of the parent process and then i am able to do what i want inside the dll. Always something to learn everyday.